# FireDAC under connecting freeze GUI

Tags: oracle, delphi

I'm facing with an issue, here is my code

```
constructor TORAThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  ORAFDcon_Ora := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  ORAFDPhysOracleDriverLink := TFDPhysOracleDriverLink.Create(nil);
  ORAFDGUIxWaitCursor := TFDGUIxWaitCursor.Create(nil);
  ORAStorPRoc := TFDStoredProc.Create(nil);
  ORAFDcon_Ora.DriverName := 'ora';
  ORAFDcon_Ora.LoginPrompt := False;
  ORAFDcon_Ora.Params.LoadFromFile('ORAconfig.ini');
  ORAFDcon_Ora.CheckConnectionDef;
  ORAFDcon_Ora.ResourceOptions.AutoConnect := True;
  ORAFDcon_Ora.ResourceOptions.AutoReconnect := True;
  ORAFDcon_Ora.ResourceOptions.KeepConnection := True;
  ORAFDcon_Ora.ResourceOptions.CmdExecMode := amNonBlocking;

procedure TORAThread.Execute;
begin
    ORAFDcon_Ora.Connected := True;
while not terminated do
begin
//somejobs
end;
```

When I start the thread and VPN connection is not alive, my GUI freezes
Whats wrong?

Regards,

Comment: I mean the VPN connection to ORA server

Comment: How can a class thread, which creates own objest freeze the main form?

Comment: I don't see enough of your code to identify the issue. This likely has nothing to do with FireDAC and instead it's probably the way you've designed this thread. What kind of communication do you have between this thread and your UI? How do you start this thread? It could be something along the lines of directly calling `Execute` instead of `Start`.

Comment: Also, your design is flawed. You shouldn't be creating those components within the thread's constructor, but instead at the beginning of `Execute`. That hints to me that you are trying to directly call `Execute` from the main thread, in which case you're not supposed to call that yourself. Take a look here: https://github.com/djjd47130/DelphiThreadDemo#can-i-use-vcl-from-a-thread

Comment: Orath := TORATHread.Create;
Orath.FreeOnTerminate := True;
Orath.Start;
No GUI interact, I know to sync the GUI

Comment: I'd say this is the `TFDGUIxWaitCursor` issue, but cannot be sure until I see the code inside (have no Delphi by hand). The purpose of the wait cursors was for the applications not using threads as far as I remember. I'd just follow [this manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Multithreading_(FireDAC)).